# Cross-browser transition and transform issues

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

I'm having issues while building my new website.

I have a mobile nav that shows up whenever your browser is small enough (I believe under 940px wide) and it works fine on Chrome and other webkit browsers, but in Firefox and IE the transitions don't work and nothing transforms the way I want it to. I'm not really sure why this is and could use help.

Here's a link to the site: http://teamreest.com/

EDIT: I am using the specific vendor prefixes, yet it still does not work.

More specifically relating to this:

```
.overlay{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: $main-color;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index:100;
  font-size:50px;
  font-weight:300;
  min-height:400px;

  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s;
  transition: -transform 0.4s;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
}

.overlay.show {
  opacity:1;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(0%);
  transform: translateX(0%);
}
```

Also this:

```
.container{
  height:100%;
  opacity: 1;

  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
  transition: -transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
}

.container.show {
  opacity: 0.5;

  -webkit-transform: translateX(30%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(30%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(30%);
  transform: translateX(30%);
}
```

Comment: webkit is used only for safari and chrome browsers for ie transform and transition will not work if version of ie is below 9 and for latest ie version use -mos properties and for firefox use -moz properties

Comment: I am using the proper vendor prefixes, but it still does not work.

Comment: can you post some code which is not working

Comment: The transition into the mobile menu on the website when using a non webkit browser is what is not working properly.
One moment, I'll take some snippets for you.

Comment: I have added the code to the main post.

Comment: can you tell me on which mobile android/ios you are checking and which browser

Comment: Latest chrome for Android and desktop,  I also believe it functions fine on safari for ios

Comment: please use the following code var x = y = 0;
for (var i = 100; i--;) {
 x = i;
 y = i * 5;
 style.left = x + 'px';
 style.top = y + 'px';
}  because chrome for mobile also partialy supports the transform and transition

Comment: so cant prdict when it will not work for mobile browser you have to do some work around for mobile and the code i have provide will also work with gr8 efficiency and not fail in any case

Comment: refer this http://www.useragentman.com/blog/2010/03/09/cross-browser-css-transforms-even-in-ie/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue in my code.

The transition as seen here:

```
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s;
  transition: -transform 0.4s;
```

And here:

```
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
  -moz-transition: -moz-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
  -ms-transition: -ms-transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
  transition: -transform 0.4s, opacity 0.4s;
```

Are problematic.  As seen, the regular transition property has an issue.
That issue can be seen as there is a dash in front of the transform property of the transition.  By removing this the problem is solved.